# Unity C# Getting Light Component from GameObject Array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, light, gameobject

Hi there I know it's a simple question but I'm beginning with unity and C#.
I have an array of 65 GameObjects and I need to use the light Component of each of them in a different array, so far I have:

```
    public GameObject[] lightGO;
    public Light[] lights;

    void Awake(){
            lightGO = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Light");
            for (int i = 0; i < lightGO.Length; i++){

                    lights[i] = lightGO[i].GetComponent<Light>();

            }

    }
```

The GameObject Array fills with the 65 items but the one with the lights keeps empty, any pointers here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the objects being loaded into `lightGO` are of the correct structure for using `GetComponent()` to retrieve a Light component? (Ie. It isn't on their children or anything like that?) Can you include a screenshot of the objects you're trying to access?

Comment: I have had some issues with using GetComponent on Lights in the past. I will need to look through my code to see what I did to get it to work.

Comment: basically I need to get an Array of a component of each one of the GameObjects I have, each GameObject has a Light Component and I successfully have the GameObjects listed within Unity but I can't get the components listed.
[image](goo.gl/photos/V5HdjYwHu4wWcdzq9 and goo.gl/photos/bzoXKmjZXvGhsfEE8

Comment: Use "GetComponentsInChildren" instead of "GetComponent", that should work.

Comment: thanks @Chad I'm using the new beta version 2017.1.0b2 hope that helps

Comment: @Herb Just wondering, where do you initialize `lights`? (Eg. Initialize a new array, set its size or whatnot.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Woltus that made the trick, I created a parent GameObject and put all the lights as its children, the code end up to be something like:

public GameObject lightsM;
        public Light[] lights;

        void Awake(){
                
                lights = lightsM.GetComponentsInChildren<Light>();
               
        }

Now everything works fine, thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @Woltus that made the trick, I created a parent GameObject and put all the lights as its children, the code end up to be something like:

```
    public GameObject lightsM;
    public Light[] lights;

    void Awake(){

            lights = lightsM.GetComponentsInChildren<Light>();

    }
```

Now everything works fine, thanks a million